# React-native-navigation registers duplicate listeners for all views

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation

Im using react-native-navigation 1.1.253. Ive a side menu(side drawer) that contain 2 buttons that navigates the user to different pages. Those pages also have a side menu. Im using deep link to navigate in the side menu and in each side menu I've

"this.props.navigator.setOnNavigatorEvent(this.onNavigatorEvent.bind(this));"

My issue is that if I go from view 1 to view 2 in my side menu my "onNavigatorEvent()" will trigger as many times I have been visting those views. Its like it register one listener for each time i visit the page.